# howto get from wsdl the methods and parameters

Tags: java, web-services, methods, parameters, wsdl

what I need to do is the following:

In java, from a wsdl I need to get the method's names and parameters of the web service in order to show them later in a form.

Is there any library that do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Has anyone tried using javax.wsdl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who is looking for something like this I've found it here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/soa-model/OKQBRoY9H8I

It uses predic8. Works perfectly fine